# Is it possible to emulate Android phone on Android tablet?

Tags: android

I have a tablet with mdpi screen (xlarge). Is it possible to emulate some other screen configurations on it? I have layouts for middle-size screens and I want to see how they will look like without using emulator (it causes a lot of pain for my PC).

For example, I've seen something like that on iPad (when its running iPhone apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can try this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

add in the manifest file

There are two versions of screen compatibility mode with slightly different behaviors:

Version 1 (Android 1.6 - 3.1)

Version 2 (Android 3.2 and greater)

***Disabling Screen Compatibility Mode***

If you've developed your application primarily for versions of Android lower than 3.0, but your application does resize properly for larger screens such as tablets, you should disable screen compatibility mode in order to maintain the best user experience. Otherwise, users may enable screen compatibility mode and experience your application in a less-than-ideal format.

By default, screen compatibility mode for devices running Android 3.2 and higher is offered to users as an optional feature when one of the following is true:

Your application has set both android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion to "10" or lower and does not explicitly declare support for large screens using the  element.
Your application has set either android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "11" or higher and explicitly declares that it does not support large screens, using the  element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10">
```

from your AndroidManifest File.

by this, if your project uses like GingerBread then it will show in 480x800

Comment: you have <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"> line in your AndroidManifest file?if yes then remove it and try